# Openrowset bulk insert on a specific row

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL, but am trying to learn its logic, I am assuming bulk insert will insert on all rows in this case a blob. (pdf file) below is my code but what I am trying to accomplish is, inserting a pdf file that I have put on SQL server in a row that has a matching Primary Key that I specify. So far I am missing the where clause to specify the PK

```
   Declare @sql varchar(max)
   Declare @filePath varchar(max)
   Set @filePath = 'C:\iphone.pdf'
   Set @sql='INSERT INTO HDData.dbo.PurchasedCellPhoneInfo(Receipt) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '''+ @filePath+''', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB'
   exec(@sql)
```

May I use an update t-SQL query instead of insert? and how would I drop the where to specify a specific row I want to insert this blob in?
Any help would be appreciated.

I also have tried this, following @misterPositive's suggestion for update query:

```
 Declare @criteria varchar(50)
 SET @criteria ='352014075399147'
 UPDATE HDData.dbo.PurchasedCellPhoneInfo SET Receipt =
 (SELECT Receipt FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\352014075399147.pdf, SINGLE_BLOB') a)
 WHERE(IMEI = @criteria)
```

i do recieve this message:
Either a format file or one of the three options SINGLE_BLOB, SINGLE_CLOB, or SINGLE_NCLOB must be specified. i like this update query as it seems to fit what im trying to do.

Comment: Is this using SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this to UPDATE:

```
UPDATE MyTable 
SET blobField = 
   (SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\Test\Test1.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) a) 
WHERE (CriteriaField = @criteria)
```

Here is another way for PK

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VWWorkDataLoad]
AS
SELECT RecordLine
FROM [dbo].[WorkDataLoad];
```

Now BULK INSERT should then look like:

```
BULK INSERT [dbo].[VWWorkDataLoad] FROM 'D:\NPfiles\TS082114.trn' 
WITH (FIRSTROW = 2,FIELDTERMINATOR = ',' , ROWTERMINATOR = '\n');
```

Comment: You can specify the PK as long as it is not identity.  At least on 2014, I have not tested other versions.

Comment: Thanks MisterPositive! i believe that worked for me sir i see a long string of characters i will try to retrieve it and see the document. but i will have to do some research and mess around with a few queries, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert new records then you could have an identity column for your PK and not have to worry about it.  I have also seen functions used when a table is designed without identity on PK.  Something like GetTableNamePK() in the select list.

If you want to update an existing record then you will want a where clause as you mentioned. This worked for me in testing:

```
Update TestBlob Set BinaryData = (SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\temp\test.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB)
    Where ID = 2
```

If you do not want to use the Identity or Function this worked where ID is a primary key and I want to insert the BLOB with PK of 3:

```
INSERT INTO TestBlob2 (ID, BinaryData) SELECT 3, * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\temp\test.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```